# PHP Loop MySQL results into array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table called `people` with the columns `id (PK)`, `fname`, and `lname`.

It's simple enough to setup a loop out of the data:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    ...do stuff...
}
```

However, what I'm looking to do is loop the column/value pairs into an array automatically.

So, if I added a new column for `email` I can call the central function and just pull from `$results['email']` while looping through the array.

Comment: What happens if you try to do that with your current code? Do you get an error? What is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc), it returns an associated array with column names as values.

Comment: This works but only returns the first result. How would I get all of the results?

Answer (score 1):

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people");
$results = array();
while(false !== ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $results[$id] = $row;
}
```

$results is now a multi-dimensional array, each element being an array of fieldname => fieldvalue elements

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [fname] => John
            [lname] => Smith
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [fname] => Karen
            [lname] => Berry
        )
)
```